# Monitor unresolved promises in when.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

when.js has the very useful monitor/console utility that provides stack traces for unhandled rejections.  Is there a similar utility or method for when.js to list any promises that haven't resolved?

In case it makes a difference here, I'm using Node.js.

Comment: What promise library are you using? This is implementation based (although work on an inspection protocol has started, RSVP has an inspector under work, and Bluebird does a much better job at handling possibly unhandled rejections (with much better stack traces) than When)

Comment: I'll edit my question to remove ambiguity; right now I'm using when.js.  At this point maintainability/debugging seems to be my greatest challenge with using promises, so if I can't find a way to better tame when.js, I may need to switch to another solution, and the Bluebird library you mentioned looks promising.